# Need to support 14k tps in java

Tags: java, performance

I need to design an application which can handle 14k tps(of UPD packets) , need to do some validations and post that push each packet to another application and get the response and update the counter of how many packets were processed.

Which technologies should I use and what should be the approach to achieve this , like should I use a blocking queue or should I persist all the records in DB then write scheduler to pick the records or should I use any other approach.

NOTE: I have a time limit of 5 mins to process each packet.

Comment: This question is too broad.  There are too many variables to provide anything other than opinion-based answers.   For example, how long will it take to *"push each packet to another application and get the response"*.  Does it matter if packets are lost?  And so on.

Comment: we have 5 mins time to push packet to another application, we have a max time of 10 secs to get the response from another application , if we don't get response in 10 sec we timeout and say packet discarded.

Comment: 1) Edit the question to add the details.  2) Do you *need* to persist records?  Why?

Comment: If you don't need to persist records, then you can probably get away with using a `PriorityQueue` to hold the packets that you have sent to the application for processing and are waiting for the responses.  This application's bottleneck will be in receiving UDP packets, sending requests and receiving responses.  All to do with network traffic.

Comment: The only thing that is potentially problematic is if you can't accept the UDP packets fast enough and they get dropped.  You could also get timeouts from the application if the rate if the incoming packet rate is too high for the application(s) to keep up with.  But it sounds like that's OK ... and not your problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.